# Query on Pivot Table

Tags: laravel

I'm new in Laravel and I need some help on a query.

I have 3 tables:

- Cables (belongs_to_many Features)
- Features (belongs_to_many Cables)
- Cable_Feature (Pivot) with pivot extra field **value**

**I have created for everyone a Model with a relationship *(and all works fine...)***

- The structure of Table Cables is (Id, Code)
- The structure of Table Features is (Id, Name)
- The structure of Pivot Table Cable_Feature is  (cable_id, feature_id, value)

> Now I need to build a query (to export in Excel with Maatwebsite/Excel). I need that every record have:

- Cables.Code
- Feature.Name
- Value

**I'm able to do it but my problem is that I need to have all on one line** *...ES: Assume that we have 3 cables and 2 features. in database*

Cables:

- (id) 1, (code) 0031TN
- (id) 2, (code) 0042GG
- (id) 3, (code) 0025ZS

Features:

- (id) 1, (name) PVC
- (id) 2, (name) CM

> And the situation in Cable_Feature is:

- 1 - 1 - High Quality
- 1 - 2 - 12
- 2 - 1 - High Quality
- 2 - 2 - 6
- 3 - 1 Low Quality
- 3 - 2 -11

Now I need to become with a query this result (1 for row)

- 0031TN - High Quality - 12
- 0042GG - High Quality - 6
- 0025ZS - Low Quality - 11

Answer (score 0):

The query, without Laravel is something like this:

```
SELECT code, 
       GROUP_CONCAT(`value`) 
FROM   cable_feature 
       JOIN cables 
         ON cables.id = cable_feature.cable_id 
GROUP  BY cables.code;
```

You can work from here to build it with Laravel Query Builder.

Bear in mind that you will need to set alter `group_concat_max_len` variable in MySQL if your group_concat value grows bigger then the limit. 
Ex: `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10000;`

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared your model code. So I assume you have relation like this in one of your model. I am using **Cable Model**

```
public function features()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Feature')
        ->withPivot('value');
}
```

Now in your controller

```
public function getAll()
    {
        $cables = Cable::all();
        foreach ($cables as $cable)
            foreach ($cable->features $feature)
            {
                echo $cable->code; //this is from the cable table
                echo $feature->name; //this is from the feature table
                echo $feature->pivot->value; //this is coming from the pivot table

            }
        }
    }
```

You  can do this in your blade too.

Comment: Right! I have the belongsToMany in my Model Cable. I know how get all feature of a Cable because I have a public function features(). My problem is how export with Maatwebsite/Excel. I need to have a column for each features ;(

Answer (score 0):

First of all thanks for the help that all you give me.

Explanation: I have write in italian (Cavi = Cables | Features = Caratteristiche)

I have resolved with a bit of code but I think is not a good super-elegant-solution (but works ;) )

The Maatwebsite/Excel package give you the ability to build $data to export. I have build all so:

```
$cavi = Cavo::with('famiglia', 'caratteristiche')->get();

        return $cavi->map(function($cavo) {
            foreach ($cavo->caratteristiche as $caratteristica) {
                if($caratteristica->id == 5 || $caratteristica->id == 7) {
                    $caratteristicheCavo[] = $caratteristica->pivot->valore;
                }
            }

            return $datiEplanArray = [
                'ParNumber' => "AGE" . $cavo->codice_articolo,
                'TypeNumber' => $cavo->famiglia->codice_articolo,
                'OrderNumber' => $cavo->codice_articolo,
                'Designation EN' => $cavo->famiglia->nome,
                'Description EN' => $cavo->famiglia->descrizione,
                'Document/Link 1' => '/ita/pdf/' . $cavo->famiglia->codice_articolo . '.pdf',
                'Description Doc. 1 EN' => '/en//pdf/' . $cavo->famiglia->codice_articolo . '.pdf',
                'ExternalDiameter / ND' => $caratteristicheCavo[1],
                'Connections / Number ' => $caratteristicheCavo[0],
                'Cable type' => $cavo->famiglia->nome,   
                'PreviewPicture' => '/immagini/' . $cavo->famiglia->immagine,
                'EDP catalogue structure level 1 EN' => 'Cavo',
            ];
        });
```